# What bathroom fan fits in this housing?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, bathroom-fixtures

I just moved into a condo and apparently the bathroom exhaust fan was removed.  Which fan fits in this housing?  Many of the ones I see online have a circular opening in the middle not like this.

The opening measures 7.5 in X 7.5 in.

[image]

Comment: Consult with condo maintenance, if any - this can't be done by "look a vague picture with no dimensions on the internet." Probably one the same physical size and you'll need to rip the box out to put it in, at a guess, if you can't determine the exact model for replacement parts..

Comment: If you clean it, you might find model # on it

Answer (score 3):

Generally the inside of an exhaust fan is not in any way standard and each manufacturer, and even different models, are constructed differently.

What is relatively standard is the cutout.  So you should be able to go to any home supply retailer and find a complete fan that will fit in this space.

Yes, you will have to go up into the attic to swap it out but based on the deteriorated condition of the one you're showing, it's probably a good idea to replace it.